# how to insert value in text box in selenium webdriver according to perticular parameter

Tags: java, html, selenium, webdriver

**This Is my java code.**

```
package com.ej.zob.modules;

import java.awt.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class SetExchange {
public void Execute(String CountryName, String value)
{
    LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.linkText("SET")).click();
    LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.linkText("EXCHANGE RATE")).click();
    //LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[.=\""+CountryName+"\"]/following-sibling::*")).findElement(By.xpath("//input[@maxlength='4']")).sendKeys(value);
    LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id=new_Afghanistan_AFN]")).sendKeys(value);
    LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.name("save")).click();
```

**This Is my html code**

```
<input id="Afghanistan_AFN" type="text" value="30" disabled="disabled">
</div>
<div style="display: table-cell;width:270px" name="cell">
<input id="new_Afghanistan_AFN" type="text" maxlength="4">
<input type="button" value="SET" onclick="setExchangeRate('Afghanistan','AFN')" name="save">
<div id="msg_Afghanistan_AFN"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<input id="Albania_ALL" type="text" value="12" disabled="disabled">
</div>
<div style="display: table-cell;width:270px" name="cell">
<input id="new_Albania_ALL" type="text" maxlength="4">
<input type="button" value="SET" onclick="setExchangeRate('Albania','ALL')" name="save">
<div id="msg_Albania_ALL"></div>
</div>
```

**I want to insert value in above text box but if I select findElement(By.id)   then it will select only perticular text box to insert value.But I want to insert value according to the country name.let us suppose if user passes afghanistan then only the text box having id afghanistan should be selected.
If I select Albania then only the text box having id albania should be selected. I already mentioned the text box in html code.**

Comment: and where exactly you are facing the problem ??

Comment: Problem is if  i am giving findelement(By.xpath"//input[@id=new_Afghanistan_AFN]") then it is selecting only afghanistan. so i want to give a country name say albania then only albania text box should be selected. hope u understand.

Comment: Still see no the problem? Just find element with Albania?

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace hard coded value like this

```
String countryName="CheckWhatUserHasSent";  --> User Selected Value
By.xpath(String.format("//input[@id=%s]",countryName));
                                    /\
                                    ||
                                    ||
      This will be replaced by whatever country Name User has passed .
```

---

**Update**

You are getting error because input box with id Albania does not exist .

You can maintain `Map<Key,Value>` where `key` is `country name` and `value` is the actual ID in html form .

```
Map<String,String> map=HashMap<>();
map.put("Albania","actualIDInHTMLFORM");
```

Now after getting country name try

```
countryName=map.get("Albania"); --> Now countryName correspond to your actual ID
```

Comment: I am getting error "Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id=Albania]"}